# How can I test a package with pycairo as a dependency with tox on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, pip, cairo, tox

I am trying to use tox to test a graphics package I am working on. One of its dependencies is pycairo, so when I set up my `tox.ini` file, I specify it under `deps` like so:

```
[testenv]
deps =
  pycairo
  ...(some other packages)
```

and while my tests work fine on Windows, when I try testing the package on MacOS, the test always fails with the following error when I try to pip-install pycairo:

```
pip3 install pycairo
```

```
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached pycairo-1.20.1.tar.gz (344 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_intel.whl (6.9 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
  Building wheel for pycairo (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for pycairo (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/appveyor/projects/cpython-cmu-graphics-0l7rb/.tox/py39/bin/python /Users/appveyor/projects/cpython-cmu-graphics-0l7rb/.tox/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/5s/g225f6nd6jl4g8tshbh1ltk40000gn/T/tmpnqn0c3o6
       cwd: /private/var/folders/5s/g225f6nd6jl4g8tshbh1ltk40000gn/T/pip-install-1vu11s7g/pycairo_6159cae3f6b14ec3a8681d1238fa6919
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/cairo
  copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/cairo
  copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/cairo
  copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/cairo
  running build_ext
  Requested 'cairo >= 1.15.10' but version of cairo is 1.12.14
  Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
Failed to build pycairo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I established that the main reason I'm getting this error is because wheels and Cairo binary files are not provided for the pip installation of pycairo on MacOS. (It's worth noting that I'm running my MacOS tests via a remote VM) As such, I tried to install cairo first using Homebrew like so:

```
brew install cairo
```

However, whenever I retry the tests, I still get the same error message. I read on another SO post that you should brew install pkg-config as well, so in addition to the brew installation above, I also did:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

And still ended up with the same error message when I retried the tests. Frustrated, I once again took to Stack Overflow and discovered that you can directly install pycairo (as well as its dependencies, like cairo) with one single brew install command:

```
brew install py3cairo
```

Now, whenever I SSH'd into the Mac VM, running the test files worked, but because tox runs tests inside of virtual environments, it can't access this version of pycairo.

Now, one nasty, probably-horrible-practice, brute-force solution I found was to print out the path of the pycairo directory using this small Python script:

```
import os
import cairo
print(os.path.dirname(cairo.__file__))
```

And then I `cp`'d that directory into a virtual environment and found that it actually allows you to run `import cairo` without getting an error.

```
cp -r <path>/cairo venv3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

```
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 26 2020, 00:12:24)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cairo
>>>
```

However, not surprisingly, this doesn't seem to work with any other Python minor version that I'm testing, and I wouldn't be surprised if this breaks the library in other ways I haven't discovered yet. So that's not really an acceptable solution either.

What can I do to make my tests run properly? In my tests I just want to simulate an environment that already has all the package dependencies installed, but with pycairo it doesn't seem like there's a way for me to access the package.

I just need this to work in tox for testing purposes only. I don't anticipate anyone using our package inside of a virtual environment, so our users should just be able to install py3cairo via brew directly to their system in the worst case.

Most likely, it looks like I need a way to install cairo and pkg-config such that pip inside of a virtual environment can access those files and still install the Python bindings. But I'm also open to any other suggestions that would just allow my tox tests to run. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> Requested 'cairo >= 1.15.10' but version of cairo is 1.12.14

Your issue is not about package discoverability but an out-of-date version. If the brew-installed version of cairo is newer than 1.15.10 then you might have a separate cairo installation lying around which gets preferred over your brew-installed version.

To reproduce the issue, I did the following:

```sh
brew install cairo
python -m venv cairo
source cairo/bin/activate
pip install pycairo
```

which worked as expected (Python 3.9.1, pip 20.2.3).

Comment: How would you suggest overriding that older installation of cairo? I couldn't find it anywhere with `find / -name cairo`, and I tried adding a few different file paths associated with the newer version to my `PATH` variable like `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/:$PATH`, `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/bin/:$PATH`, and `export PATH=/usr/local/lib/cairo/:$PATH`. But none of them worked. Any ideas as to how I could address this?